# Web application made "Native" with Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have a mobile web application that is published in a designated URL.

If I want users to access the web-app by installing an application (besides just browsing to the URL from their mobile) can I use Phonegap for this? This app should only be used when the user is online.

One of the solutions I had in mind is to create a Phonegap app that holds an `<iframe>` to the relevant URL. Is there a different way? Are there any disadvantages in my solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cordova aka phonegap just to load the website, I would not recommend to use it as it will make you application bit heavy.
The Simple technique would be to include a webview component in your screen/page and load the url using the following code your activity class

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    public class Main extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebview;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mWebview = new WebView(this);
            mWebview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            setContentView(mWebview);
        }
 }
```